# Change fat jar name in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have a Spring Boot project and I am creating fat jar and normal jars with gradle.

When I run "gradle clean build" , it creates 2 jar files. First one is the fat one, named 'abc.jar' and the second one is normal one with name 'abc.jar.original'.

When I run "gradle installDist", it is creating the the normal jar with name 'abc.jar'.

What I wanna do is, in clean build, I wanna create the fat jar with name 'abc-all.jar' and normal one with the name 'abc.jar'. So fat and normal jar will not overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your fatjar config

archiveName = "${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}-all.${extension}"

Answer (score 0):

I used doLast and simply rename the file names.

```
build.doLast{
def jarName = jar.archiveName
def fatJarName = jarName.replaceAll('.jar','-all.jar')

def jarFullPath = "$project.buildDir/libs/"+jarName
def fatJarFullPath = "$project.buildDir/libs/"+fatJarName


if ( file(fatJarFullPath).exists() ) {
    file(fatJarFullPath).delete()
}

//rename fat jar's name
file( jarFullPath ).renameTo( file( fatJarFullPath ) )


if ( file(jarFullPath+'.original').exists() ) {
    file(jarFullPath).delete()
}

//rename slim jar's name
file(jarFullPath+'.original').renameTo(file(jarFullPath))
```

}